# Understanding the proof of a theorem in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

I don't understand the proof of theorem 2.10 in the book (page 112) of Allen Hatcher on algebraic topology.

It states: Two homotopic maps induce the same homomorphism on homology groups.

Here is the part I'm stuck with:

[image]

When he calculates $\partial P(\sigma)$, I do not understand how the terms with $i = j$ cancel, and how we are left with the terms he says we do. I tried to do this explicitly for an easy example but it didn't work out. Any help is appreciated here.

Also, I don't understand why the terms with $i \neq j$ are $- P \partial (\sigma)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Hatcher's result is correct, his "cancellation" explanation needs clarification.

For a singular $m$-simplex $\tau : \Delta^m \to X$, where $\Delta^m = [u_0,\dots,u_m]$, we write $d_k(\tau) = \tau \mid [u_0,\dots,\hat{u}_k,\ldots,u_m]$ for $k = 0,\ldots, m$.

Let us abbreviate $F \circ (\sigma \times \mathbb I)$ by $\phi$. Then we have
$$P(\sigma) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n]$$
$$\partial P(\sigma) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \partial (\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n]) \\= \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \sum_{j=0}^{n+1} (-1)^jd_j(\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n]) \\= \sum_{i,j} (-1)^{i+j}d_j(\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n]) \\ = \sum_{j \le i \le n} (-1)^{i+j}d_j(\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n]) + \\ \sum_{n+1 \ge j > i} (-1)^{i+j}d_j(\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n]) \\= \sum_{j \le i \le n} (-1)^{i+j} \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat{v}_j,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n] + \\ \sum_{n+1 \ge j > i} (-1)^{i+j}\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,\hat{w}_{j-1},\ldots,w_n] \\ =
\sum_{j \le i \le n} (-1)^{i+j} \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat{v}_j,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n] + \\ \sum_{n \ge j \ge i} (-1)^{i+j+1}\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,\hat{w}_{j},\ldots,w_n]$$
Now you see that each term indexed by $(i,i)$ with $n \ge i > 0$ in the first sum cancels with the term indexed by $(i-1,i-1)$ in the second sum. Thus only the terms indexed by $(0,0)$ in the first sum and by $(n,n)$ in the second sum survive. These are $\phi \mid [w_0,\ldots,w_n] = g_\#(\sigma)$ and $-\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_n] = -f_\#(\sigma)$. Thus we get
$$\partial P(\sigma) - g_\#(\sigma) + f_\#(\sigma) = \\\sum_{j < i \le n} (-1)^{i+j} \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat{v}_j,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,w_n] +\\ \sum_{n \ge j > i} (-1)^{i+j+1}\phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots,\hat{w}_{j},\ldots,w_n]$$
For each face $d_j(\sigma) = \sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_n]$ we have to consider the prism with bottom $[v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_n]$ and top $[w_0,\ldots,\hat w_j,\ldots, w_n]$. We get
$$P \partial \sigma = P(\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j d_j(\sigma)) = \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j P(d_j(\sigma)) =  \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j P(\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_n])=\\ \sum_j (-1)^j \left(\sum_{i<j}(-1)^i \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots\hat w_j,\ldots, w_n] + \\ \sum_{i\ge j}(-1)^i \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_{i+1},w_{i+1},\ldots w_n]\right) \\= \sum_{i < j} (-1)^{i+j} \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,v_i,w_i,\ldots\hat w_j,\ldots, w_n] + \\ \sum_{i > j} (-1)^{i+j+1} \phi \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_{i},w_{i},\ldots w_n]$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In the fourth line above, you put the sums over $i$ and $j$ together as $\sum_{i,j}$. But in the third line, $j$ goes from $ 0$ to $n+1$, while $i$ goes from $i = 0$ to $i = n$. So how can you put them together?

Comment: $\sum_{i,j}$ is just an abbreviation for $\sum_{(i,j) \in \{0,\dots,n\} \times\{0,\dots,n+1\}  }$.

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant answer. I would never be able to do it with all the indices xD

Comment: I think your reasoning in computing $P∂(σ)$ is wrong. There will not be $j≥i$ in the second sum. Once you remove $v_j$ then that vertex cannot appear in the sum in any circumstances. The finite sequence of simplices over which the sum has been taken for $i>j$ can be described as follows $:$
$$[v_0,\cdots, \widehat {v_j}, \cdots, v_n, w_n]\ \\ \big\downarrow\\ [v_0,\cdots, \widehat {v_j}, \cdots, v_{n-1}, w_{n-1},w_n]\\  {\big \downarrow}\\ \vdots \\ \big\downarrow\\ [v_0,\cdots, \widehat {v_j}, v_{j+1},w_{j+1},\cdots, w_n].$$

Comment: Sorry in the first comment I want to mean that there should not be $i \geq j$ in the second sum as running index. Instead it should be $i  \gt j.$ As $i \gt j$ and we have removed the $j$-th vertex, the $i$-th vertex will become $(i-1)$-th vertex and that's why the sign becomes $(-1)^{i - 1}.$ Here there is no substitution involved which you have wrongly argued in your answer.

Comment: @Anacardium Write $[v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_n] = [v'_0,\dots,v'_{n-1}]$ as the bottom and  $[w_0,\ldots,\hat w_j,\ldots, w_n] = [w'_0,\dots,w'_{n-1}]$ as the top. Then you get $P(\sigma \mid [v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_n]) = P(\sigma \mid [v'_0,\dots,v'_{n-1}]) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \phi \mid [v'_0,\dots,v'_i,w'_i, \dots, w'_{n-1}] = \sum_{0 \le i < j} \phi \mid [v'_0,\dots,v'_i,w'_i, \dots, w'_{n-1}] +  \sum_{j \le i \le n-1} \phi \mid [v'_0,\dots,v'_i,w'_i, \dots, w'_{n-1}]$ and you can check what

Comment: $[v'_0,\dots,v'_i,w'_i, \dots, w'_{n-1}]$ is in terms of $[v_0,\ldots,\hat v_j,\ldots, v_n]$ and $[w_0,\ldots,\hat w_j,\ldots, w_n]$.

Comment: I don't think my reasoning is incorrect. I don't understand how $v_j$ will appear as one of the vertices of the simplices (over which we are restricting $\phi$ and taking sum) after it is removed which you have argued in your answer.

Comment: @Anacardium $v_j, w_j$ do not appear -look at my answer. But if you think it is incorrect, you should write your own answer.

Comment: @Paul Frost I am not saying that it is incorrect. Actually I have interpreted the same thing from different angle. I think my argument is equally valid as that of yours.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, the idea is that the term from the first sum with $i=j$ will cancel from the term in the second sum with $i-1=j-1$. It might be better to write the first sum as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} ...$ and similarly for the second sum. The $(i,i)$ term in the first sum will cancel with the $(i-1,i-1)$ term in the second sum: the signs will be opposite, and the simplices from the two sums will be the same:
$$
[v_0, ..., v_{i-1}, \hat{v}_i, w_i, ..., w_n], \quad
[v_0, ..., v_{i-1}, \hat{w}_{i-1}, w_i, ..., w_n].
$$
The remaining terms will come from the first sum when $i=0$ and from the second sum when $i=n$, since those are not part of the cancellation.

For the second part ($i \neq j$ terms), what part of Hatcher's explanation is not clear?